# How to deal with funds lost to rounding errors in DeFi protocols?

Tags: solidity, defi, floating-point, fixed-point

What are the different methods that DeFi protocols use to handle rounding errors? For example say I have an ICO contract that returns 1/1e10 of the ICO token per ETH, so if you deposit 1 ETH(1e18 wei) you should get back 1e8 ICO wei, hence if you deposit less than 1e10 ETH wei you'll get zero tokens.

My initial thoughts regarding how developers could preempt this would be by requiring at least 1e10 ETH deposited, but even then if the deposit amount is `x + y` where `x >= 1e10` and `y < 1e10` you still have a rounding error with `y`, so the devs preempt this as well by requiring the `deposit%1e10 == 0`, but this limits all valid amounts that do not have rounding errors that are not a multiple of 1e10 from being deposited. So the devs instead allow all amounts `>= 1e10` but find `x` and `y`, compute the ICO tokens using `x` and return `y` back to the sender.

I'm not certain any of the solutions would work and even if it does it may only be applicable to a subset of DApps, which probably doesn't include DEX/AMMs or DeFi lending protocols at least not in a gas efficient way. So are there better more universally applicable solutions for dealing with rounding errors?

Comment: Some contracts like MakerDao or Uniswap use extra precision when required, but otherwise the truncation errors are usually ignored. In blockchain it is commonly called "dust", small quantities whose processing cost is greater than its value.