# Is there a math error in solidity?

Tags: solidity, math

I'm getting a rounding error in solidity that I'm not getting in python

```
    uint contributor_balance = 51.50350 ether;

    uint principal = 21.756 ether;

    uint WAD = 1000000000000000000;

    uint percent_used = contributor_balance * WAD / principal;

    uint contribution = contributor_balance * WAD / percent_used;
    
    return contribution;
```

This is returning a `contribution` of `21756000000000000003`, but it should be `21756000000000000000`. Python is returning the correct number for the same formula. Getting the same wrong number in solidity with a fixed point math library

Comment: I have answered below. By the way, you may also be interested in using a [fixed-point math library](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math) rather than implementing your own custom approaches.

Comment: Yeah I've used one. Mentioned that in the last sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a math error according to Python. I've tested in Remix and got `21756000000000000003`. I did the calculations in Google and even got a different answer than `21756000000000000000`. The precision depends on whether it's acceptable to your requirement.

Comment: Yeah also tried with Google's calculator, and it's wrong. How do people do math for DeFi protocols when solidity has a math error? I've tried Solamate's FixedPointMathLib but I'm still getting the error

Comment: See: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120144/how-to-deal-with-funds-lost-to-rounding-errors-in-defi-protocols

Answer (score 2):

Solidity is providing the correct answer, Python is the one that is wrong.  You haven't showed your python code, but my guess is that you are using some sort of floating point type for the numbers, which means `contributor_balance * WAD / principal` is getting rounded off.  Solidity supports integers up to 256 bits, and the provided algorithm fits well within that range so there is no rounding.

However, Solidity *will* truncate to the nearest integer, which is happening here and why your math doesn't result in the same number out as it does in.

Equivalent in JavaScript using integer math:

```
const a = 51503500000000000000n
const b = 21756000000000000000n
var c = a * 10n**18n / b
var d = a * 10n**18n / c

console.log(c)
// 2367323956609670895n
console.log(d)
// 21756000000000000003n
```

And using double precision floating point math in JavaScript:

```
const a = 51503500000000000000
const b = 21756000000000000000
var c = a * 10**18 / b
var d = a * 10**18 / c 

console.log(c)
// 2367323956609670700
console.log(d)
// 21756000000000000000
```

Notice how `c` is rounded off when using double precision floating point numbers.  I don't know what Python uses internally, but I get `2367323956609670656` for `c` (which is a bit surprising, as it doesn't appear to be rounded as a double, but also doesn't appear to be doing integer math either).

Comment: For Python, I was using the same formula except replacing ```ether``` with ```* WAD```. It's correct, because the formula it's a simplified version of something that's meant to calculate a account's contribution to a payment & Solidity is returning a contribution as 3 wei over the original payment. It seems like Solidity shares the precision errors of Js. Anyway I got rid of it by adding 0's to WAD / increasing precision

Comment: Solidity is doing integer math and it is giving an exact and correct number (same as JavaScript when using bigints).  The behavior you are seeing in Python is that it is likely doing some sort of floating point or decimal math which is not the same as doing integer math, and will give you a different result.  Looking at the intermediate output from python suggests to me that the fact it gave out the same value that it got in is a coincidence, not that it is doing something more correctly.

Comment: As an extreme example, imagine that you do a calculation that gives you a rational number out that couldn't be represented in base 2 even given infinite digits (e.g., pi, or e).  Then imagine you did the operation in reverse with that output being used as input (just like you have here).  Unless the computer stores the original input algorithm (rather than the output) and then simplifies the final equation for you (which is not what Python is doing), then you will get a different number out than you got in unless you get lucky with the inputs.

Comment: @RyanSea Looks like you forgot to use `//` in Python? Please accept Micah's answer if it's correct. Comments don't show code well so I posted a Python equivalent of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @Micah's answer, Solidity is correct.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#division

> Since the type of the result of an operation is always the type of one of the operands, division on integers always results in an integer. In Solidity, division rounds towards zero.

In Python, using `//` instead of `/` appears to do the trick.

Here is Python showing the same Solidity result `21756000000000000003`.

```
>>> a = 51503500000000000000
>>> b = 21756000000000000000
>>> c = a * 10**18 // b
>>> d = a * 10**18 // c
>>> c 
2367323956609670895
>>> d
21756000000000000003
```

(Same results as the Javascript @Micah posted.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple native math errors in Solidity, but they are technically called [panics](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/control-structures.html#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require).

ForgeStd has a library for panic codes called [`stdError`](https://github.com/foundry-rs/forge-std/blob/80b66ff40d9471e4331720f426e4ae177218bdd4/src/StdError.sol). The codes most relevant to you would be:

- `arithmeticError` (overflow 2^256)
- `divisionError` (divide by zero)

Comment: I don't mean a panic, I mean solidity is doing imprecise math